# Using a vkFence with an std::condition_variable

Tags: callback, synchronization, vulkan, condition-variable

A `VkFence` can be [waited upon](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2-extensions/man/html/vkWaitForFences.html) or [queried about its state](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2-extensions/man/html/vkGetFenceStatus.html). Is it possible to have a callback invoked by the Vulkan implementation when the fence is ready instead?

This would allow it to be used with objects such as a `std::condition_variable`. When the fence would be ready, the `condition_variable` would get notified.

Such an approach would also allow integration with libraries like [Boost.Fiber](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/libs/fiber/doc/html/index.html), which would completely remove the need for the thread to sleep, but rather it could do useful work while waiting upon the fence.

If this is not possible in base Vulkan, is there an extension that allows it?

Comment: "*which would completely remove the need for the thread to sleep*" Not waiting on the fence while you have useful work to do could also do that.

Comment: @NicolBolas I wanted to ask if a callback exists as using `condition_variable`s and Boost.Fiber seems more convenient and scalable to me than manually scheduling. The work to be done when I would otherwise be waiting upon the fence could be selected by a scheduler instead of me. I think that a scheduler could also do a better job and result in higher performance, as I saw an example of that in a [Naughty Dog GDC talk](https://www.gdcvault.com/play/1022186/Parallelizing-the-Naughty-Dog-Engine).

Comment: Again, why would you be spending time waiting on the fence instead of doing that stuff? Generally speaking, you only wait on a fence when you've rendered so much stuff that you outran the GPU and now must drop a frame. At which point... you've dropped a frame; who cares what the performance is.

Comment: @NicolBolas Indeed, the fence was used to wait for an image to become available for acquiring from the swapchain. I didn't really think about the implications of waiting for it and that the application will have to pause anyway before rendering anything more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vulkan doesn't work that way. Vulkan devices and queues execute independently of the CPU. Indeed, with one or two exceptions, Vulkan implementations only *ever* use CPU resources within the scope of a particular function call and only on the thread on which this call was made. Even debug callbacks are made within the scope of the function that caused the error.

There is no mechanism for Vulkan implementations to use CPU resources without the explicit consent of the user of the API (again, minus one or two exceptions). So no callbacks that act outside of an API call.

Vulkan does have a way to extract a native synchronization object from a `VkFence`, but it is surprisingly not useful in Windows. While you can get a `HANDLE`, it cannot be used by the Win32 API for waiting on it. This is mainly for interop with other APIs (like converting it to a D3D12 sync object), not for waiting on it yourself. But the file descriptor extraction operation can get a fully functional sync object... if the implementation lets you.